# Magento Admin - Favicon option not present in Configuration - Design - HTML Head

Tags: magento, backend, favicon

I'm running Magento 1.7.0.2 with multistore and I would like to change the favicon of my stores but the favicon option is disappeared from the Config - Design - HTML Head where it should be.

The file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml contain the reference to this option
and the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php is present.

Any suggestion?
Thanks
Enrico

Comment: Do you use any custom extensions? The favicon option should be there no matter what scope do you select.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply replace the default favicon with your own in /skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico location

Comment: unfortunately I'm in a multistore environment so I can not change it for all of the store but each one should have his own.

Answer (score 1):

Was a broken installation, I tried all of your suggestion without success. The site had, during the time many website and store view added and removed. Many themes and customization. We decide to split it in different vhost now all it's more clean and smouth.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screenshot of System -> configuration -> Design that show 'Current Configuration Scope' and 'Favicon Icon' see example below

[image]

Comment: Favicon Icon is missing my first entry is Default Title. I can not load images because I'm a "young" user, but trust me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did you try temporary disable all custom module to see if one of them is causing this issue or download a fresh copy of magento and do a 'diff' to see if their is any modification to core?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, thanks iin advance for the simple idea, I didn,y think to that.